# Url friendly htaccess PHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a product page and need the user to access it , but with the product name.

```
How it works: localhost/product?id=2

I want it that way: localhost/computer
```

My code .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^confirmation/?$ confirmation.php [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/product/([^/]+)/$ product.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Is not working, where I'm going wrong ?

Comment: New way is localhost/computer or localhost/product/computer?

Comment: What do "Old way" and "New way" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^confirmation/?$ confirmation.php [NC,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```